# grunt-contrib-watch exits silently

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-watch

I use the grunt-contrib-watch task (v. 0.5.3) in order to enable LiveReload:

```
        livereload: {
            options: {
               middleware: function (connect) {
                           return [lrSnippet, mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'), 
                           mountFolder(connect, 'src'),
                           proxySnippet];
               }
            }
        }

    //...some other tasks...


        watch: {
                    livereload: {
                        options: {
                            livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                        },
                        files: [
                            'src/*.html'
                        ]
                    }
               }

//...................................

grunt.registerTask('server', [
        'clean:server',
        'recess:compile',
        'configureProxies',
        'connect:livereload',
        'open',
        'watch'
    ]);
```

While running `grunt server --verbose` (including `watch` task), I end up with this console output:

```
Running "watch" task
    Waiting...Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.livereload.files exists in config...OK
    Live reload server started on port: 35729
    Watching src/404.html for changes.
    Watching src/app for changes.
    Watching src/assets for changes.
    Watching src/common for changes.
    Watching src/less for changes.
    Watching src/vendor for changes.
    Watching src/index.html for changes.
```

For instance, we see here that `src/index.html` is observed, thus I attempt to change the page title  to see the live modification. But, process exits as soon as I save my file..

I read about the fact that `watch` task may exit if the provided file paths are invalid. 
But, `Watching src/index.html for changes` asserts that it exists, doesn't it?

I don't figure it out.

Comment: Are you using a Livereload browser extension or loading the script in your index page?

Comment: @elclanrs I don't use a browser extension, I use the standard way provided by Yeoman generator.

Comment: Here's my whole gruntfile.js: https://gist.github.com/mica16/c9051f232ac1294eb236 although the interesting part is the `watch` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was.... a [bug](http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/204) with NodeJs 0.10.18.

I updated to 0.10.21 and the whole works without changing anything in my first Gist.

**In one word, if you have OSX 10.9 (Mavericks), you have to update Node to 0.10.21**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the issue you're having, but it seems like you're using the connect-livereload middleware directly instead of setting the livereload option directly, as supported by [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect).

Here's a simple example GruntFile, using just grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-connect:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 12345;

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: './src',
          livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      develop: {
        files: 'src/*.html',
        options: {
          livereload: {
            port: LIVERELOAD_PORT
          }
        }
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'connect:server',
    'watch'
  ]);
};
```

If you don't need to configure a specific port and can use the default port, it's even simpler - just change the livereload properties for both tasks to true:

```
livereload: true
```

Comment: Thanks but I've just tried it, but same effect :(  This kind of middleware was generated by Yeoman. I just use the default.

Comment: Too bad... Did you try the example as is first, to see if just the two tasks work ok together?

Does watch exists also when you simply run "grunt watch:livereload"?
Btw, noticed that the file mask is different in your gist and the GruntFile snippet.

Comment: Yes, my Gist is slightly different but the issue remains the same. I'm going retry your solution right now as itself.

Comment: So, I exactly tried this: https://gist.github.com/mica16/e7a934717e615fae1a22, and exactly same issue... The file is watched but as soon as a modification is made (adding some text in `index.html`'s title part), the watch process exits and nothing happens.

Comment: I found the problem (see my answer below). Thanks you a lot for your help!